# How to get square-root of negative number, e.g., sqrt(-3)?

Tags: r

Given `x<--3`, I tried to get its square root (I know it should be an imaginary number), but it seems not working:

```
> sqrt(x)
[1] NaN
Warning message:
In sqrt(x) : NaNs produced
```

Is there any way to make it fly? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `as.complex`

```
> sqrt(as.complex(x))
[1] 0+1.732051i
```

Comment: if you want a shortcut: `sqrt(x+0i)`

Comment: @BenBolker Thanks!